# Acitverecord specify `inverse_of` with `through` but not the other way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, rails-activerecord

I have 3 models as follows :

```rb
class User
  has_many :event_series, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :events, through: :event_series, inverse_of: :user
end

class EventSeries
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :event_series
  has_many :events, inverse_of: :event_series
end

class Event
  belongs_to :event_series, inverse_of: :events
  has_one :user, through: :event_series, inverse_of: :events
end
```

This is all fine.
Now I want to add a special event for each user called the 'showcase_event'.

```rb
class User
  has_one :showcase_event, class_name: 'Event', inverse_of: :user
end
```

This isn't working because the `Event` model doesn't have the user directly, it's associated through `EventSeries`.

I'm getting an error during serialization:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column events.user_id does not exist
```

I'm using fast jsonapi:

```rb
class PublicUserSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  ...
  has_one :showcase_event, record_type: :event, serializer: EventSerializer
  ...
end
```

It seems to me that the inverse relationship that I have between `User`, `Event` and `EventSeries` needs to work between `User` and `showcase_event` but I don't know how to specify that ONLY the inverse is through `EventSeries`
Apologies in advance for not having the best vocabulary to describe this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by my rubber duck.
As seen in the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods) :

> The `#belongs_to` association is always used in the model that has the
>   foreign key.

So I changed my declaration of the `showcase_event` to this :

```
class User
  belongs_to :showcase_event, class_name: 'Event', inverse_of: :user, optional: true
end
```

And problem solved